# Dapper multi-parameter stored procedure query returns nothing back from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, dapper

I have been using Dapper as my ORM for my .NET Core Web Api.

When using Dapper to query a stored procedure from my database with one parameter, it works exactly as expected. When I add more than one parameter, it does not return anything back to my datamodel like it should.

I suspect this has to do either with my syntax or the way I am structuring the query. The stored procedure I am using below works as expected when executed inside a SSMS query window.

Here is my method containing the Dapper Query in my DAL:

```
public List<Players> C_GetAllActivePlayersInSport(int orgID, int sportID)
    {
        using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            var returnedData = db.Query<Players>("dbo.spPlayers_GetAllActivePlayers_by_Sport @orgID, @sportID", new { orgID = orgID, sportID = sportID }).ToList();

            return returnedData;
        }
    }
```

The values passed in make it to the method and query above, but after the query executes, it returns a list with a count of 0.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
var returnedData = db.Query<Players>(
    "dbo.spPlayers_GetAllActivePlayers_by_Sport",
        new { orgID, sportID }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
```

(note: `.AsList()` would be marginally preferable)

Comment: This solved the issue. Should I be using commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure for single parameter stored procedure queries as well?