# Stored procedure doesn't return any data when being called from the C# code

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

I have a stored procedure that accepts around 8 parameters and returns a bunch of data. The stored procedure itself runs fine and it returns the data when I call it in SSMS. But when I call it from my application using Dapper ORM, I don't get any data back.

I looked up similar threads here and I've tried everything that was suggested like this one: [Dapper multi-parameter stored procedure query returns nothing back from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51937392/dapper-multi-parameter-stored-procedure-query-returns-nothing-back-from-database)

Here's my code:

```
localConnection = new SqlConnection(defaultSettings.SetConnectionString(auth.DB_Name));

var parameters = new DynamicParameters();

try
{
    parameters.Add("@param2", "val1");
    parameters.Add("@param3", "val2");
    parameters.Add("@param4", "val3");
    parameters.Add("@param5", "val4");
    parameters.Add("@param6", "val5");
    parameters.Add("@param7", "val6");
    parameters.Add("@param8", "val7");

    var orders = localConnection.Query<Order>("spGetData", parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    log.Error("Getdata Error: " + ex.Message);
}
```

Here's the SQL Server stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetData]
     @param1 VARCHAR(8),         
     @param2 VARCHAR(8),        
     @param3 VARCHAR(8),         
     @param4 VARCHAR(8),        
     @param5 VARCHAR(8),         
     @param6 VARCHAR(8),         
     @param7 VARCHAR(8) 
AS        
    SET NOCOUNT ON    

    SELECT TOP 1 * 
    FROM Orders a 
    JOIN ChangeLog b ON a.id = b.id
    WHERE a.name = @param1 
      AND a.col2 = @param2  
      AND b.col1 = @param3
      AND b.col3 = @param4 
      AND b.col4 = @param5 
      AND a.col3 = @param6 
      AND b.col5 = @param7

    RETURN 0
```

Any idea what is going on? Or what is it that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Show the code where you read your value out of param1? I can't see it but it might just be later in the code.

Comment: What does your SQL look like? You should also wrap you `localConnection` in a `using` block

Comment: I haven't coded for that piece yet. It just returns any error messages if the stored procedure fails

Comment: @Liam: SQL is just a stored proc that performs data extraction. It runs fine, I get the data when I execute the stored proc manually and it also runs fine when being called from another existing application (although there we are using ADO.NET)

Comment: @CaiusJard: Even if I remove the output parameter "param1" from the stored procedure and the code, I still don't get any data.

Comment: Try removing the NOCOUNT. Just a wild guess. That used to mess with older ORMs, which used the row count metadata to know it had rows to load. Not sure if it does for dapper though. Also make sure you have a primary key defined for your entity. That killed me with an nhibernate issue once.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the curly brace after the line that calls the procedure. Then hover the mouse over orders and see if there are any helpful error messages.

Comment: @Nikki9696: I removed the NOCOUNT, still no data. I do have a primary key.

Comment: @dev1998: There's no error messages, just doesn't return any data.

Comment: Well boo. Ok, you say it doesn't return any data. Can you post the snippet where you are trying to get/output the data? I see you declared a variable here, orders, but I don't see it used. i assume you just omited it for brevity but can you post where and how you iterate over "orders"?

Comment: @Nikki9696: I just hover over the orders variable to see if it returns any data. It doesn't . If it does, I have to code for the part where I use it.

Comment: Just for grins, see if the issue is actually with the IDE. Pop out a quick count or something like orders.Count or grab a FirstOrDefault into a var and output it to console. One time, I WAS getting results, and because of a bug, the IDE didn't show them. If that's not it, that's all I got. Good luck.

Comment: I got it working. It was an issue with the "Order" class , The properties in the Order class didn't match the Stored proc output column names. Once I fixed that, i got the data. Sorry to waste your time on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no problem with Dapper and multiple parameters as far as I can see. Here's a test code I created:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(@"Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=tempdb;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS");

        c.Execute(@"
CREATE PROCEDURE GetPerson(
    @N VARCHAR(10),
    @A INT,
    @S INT
)AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @N as Name, @A as Age, @S as Salary;
END;");

        //works
        var p = c.Query<Person>("GetPerson", new { A = 1, N = "John", S = 1000 }, commandType: System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure);

        //doesn't work, "procedure expects parameter @A which was not supplied"
        int i = 2, j = 2000; string n = "Frank";
        var q = c.Query<Person>("GetPerson", new { i, n, j }, commandType: System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure);

        //works
        int A = 3, S = 3000; string N = "Joe";
        var r = c.Query<Person>("GetPerson", new { S, A, N }, commandType: System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure);

        //works
        DynamicParameters dp = new DynamicParameters();
        dp.Add("@A", 4);
        dp.Add("@N", "Derek");
        dp.Add("@S", 4000);
        var s = c.Query<Person>("GetPerson", dp, commandType: System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure);

        DynamicParameters dp2 = new DynamicParameters();
        dp2.Add("A", 5);
        dp2.Add("N", "Tim");
        dp2.Add("S", 5000);
        var t = c.Query<Person>("GetPerson", dp2, commandType: System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure);

    }
}

class Person
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

All the queries that `//works` return a list of 1 person. The Salary column output by the query is not represented in the Person class so it just gets lost.

Key takeaways from this:

- dapper is flexible about how it accepts parameters
- dapper parameter name is important
- dapper doesn't care about @ in a parameter name
- query columns that have no matching property in the strong class are not represented

And as you identified it's the last one that was critical in your case; your query wasn't outputting columns with names that matched your orders object

Comment: I've removed the output param from the stored proc and the code. I was just using it to capture any errors returned by the stored proc. Even after that, I'm not getting any data

Comment: I have added the SQL code in the original post now.

Comment: I'm uncertain whether the parameter naming makes a difference, but it might, can you correct your c# parameter names (`@param2 - @param8`) so they are `@param1 - @param7`, and also show a screenshot of calling the procedure in SSMS that shows how it runs there OK and definitely returns data

Comment: ps; does `var orders = localConnection.Query<Order>("spGetData", new[] { param1 = "val1", param2 = "val2", param3 = "val3", param4 = "val4", param5 = "val5", param6 = "val6", param7 = "val7" } , commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();` work?

Comment: I got it working. It was an issue with the "Order" class , The properties in the Order class didn't match the Stored proc output column names. Once I fixed that, i got the data. Sorry to waste your time on this.

Comment: No apologies; It was a nice intro to dapper for me :)

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. The `Order` class I'm using has properties that should match the stored procedure's data columns, which it was not.

Once I fixed that, I got it working.